# I can't run a apt-get update

Tags: apt, server, raspberrypi

I recently just installed a 32-bit version of Ubuntu Server 20.04 on my Raspberry Pi, mainly so I could set up a Counter-Strike server. I tried installing SteamCMD and it gave me an error saying:

```
"Package steamcmd is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only
available from another source."
```

I read up online and one site told me I should update my apt, but I couldn't because it gives me this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

So, I'm stuck. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: armv7 is not the same thing as i386.  They are different architectures and incompatible.

Comment: Then what do I do?

Comment: i386 is the 32-bit x86 architecture; so it needs an amd/intel x86 cpu (amd64 is the x86_64 or 64-bit architecture).  Raspberry pi uses armv7 (32-bit) or arm64 (64-bit) which is different.  Your choice is use a amd64 machine, or use packages/programs available for armv7/armhf/arm64 which your PI can use.

Comment: This question has been asked before, I know as I've answered it... looking for the duplicate..  (can't find what I was looking for sorry)

Comment: please note: my advice is generic, I don't know the program (game?) to which you speak, so have no special knowledge.  It's just based on programs compiled for one architecture will 99.9% not run on a different CPU architecture (unless they were intended to do so, eg. amd64 created by AMD was intended to be intel x86 compatible, where as intel's IA64 was not so IA64 today is dead, intel today use amd64 as well as amd64 won out in the marketplace)

Comment: I found out the program I am using can not run on ARM, so thank you for telling me.